# Pyspark combine values with same condition into new column as a list

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a table with several repeated values as following:

```
| name | value |
|------|-------|
| a    | 1     |
| a    | 2     |
| b    | 1     |
| c    | 3     |
| c    | 4     |
| c    | 5     |
```

I'd like to group this into following format:

```
| name | value |
|------|-------|
| a    |[1,2]  |
| b    |[1]    |
| c    |[3,4,5]|
```

Can anyone share a concise way to do this gracefully please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `collect_list` function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

......
df = df.groupBy('name').agg(F.collect_list('value').alias('value'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using collect_set to keep unique values in an array field.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).